# Use python eval() in method calls

Tags: python, django, logging, error-handling

I have used `eval()` before but I'm trying to use it in a method call and it's not working.

```
    if level == 'info':
            logging.info(
                f"Date:{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}, Ran with args: {args}, and kwargs: {kwargs}"
            )
        elif level == 'warning':
            logging.warning(
                f"Date:{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}, Ran with args: {args}, and kwargs: {kwargs}"
            )
        elif level == 'error':
            logging.error(
                f"Date:{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}, Ran with args: {args}, and kwargs: {kwargs}"
            )
        elif level == 'critical':
            logging.critical(
                f"Date:{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}, Ran with args: {args}, and kwargs: {kwargs}"
            )
```

How do I make less code by using something like:

```
    level == 'info':
    logging.eval(level)(
                f"Date:{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}, Ran with args: {args}, and kwargs: {kwargs}"
            )
```

I really thought this last one was gonna work:

```
    level = 'info'
    log = f"{logging}.{eval(level)}"
        eval(log)(f"Date:{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}, Ran with args: {args}, and kwargs: {kwargs}")
```

Anyone knows a way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `eval` is usually a bad idea.  You could use `getattr`, e.g.:

```
getattr(logging, level)(
    f"Date:{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}, Ran with args: {args}, and kwargs: {kwargs}"
)
```

That way you aren't executing arbitrary code based on what `level` contains, just trying to get an attribute of that name from `logging` (and raising `AttributeError` immediately if it's not valid).

FWIW, I would implement this the other way around -- have this method `return` the logging string, and have the *caller* supply that to `logging.whatever`.  The caller already needs to know which specific `logging` function it's calling; if you just have it call the actual function rather than passing its name as a string literal, it's easier to catch typos/etc via static analysis.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this and its simple if i understand  :-

```
error = {
    'info':logging.info,
    'warning':logging.warning,
    'error':logging.error,
    'critical':logging.critical,
}
massage = f"Date:{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}, Ran with args: {args}, and kwargs: {kwargs}"
error.get(level)(massage)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use the `logging.log` function from logging?

```
loggging.log(level, msg)
```

See [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)